# Would replacing the SSD on a 14" MacBook Pro void warranty or make Apple deny service?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, warranty

I have a 14" MacBook Pro with 512GB of internal storage, but I feel like this is not enough for my needs.

I recently acquired a broken 14" MacBook Pro with 1TB of internal storage and am considering replacing the 512GB SSD in my MacBook Pro with the 1TB SSD from the broken MacBook Pro. My concern is that doing this will void the warranty or cause Apple to deny me service in the future due to the mismatch between the specification associated with the serial number and the actual storage in the computer.

I will not be able to keep the other memory module as I plan on selling the broken MacBook Pro, so I won't be able to switch the 512 GB module back before sending my MacBook in for service.

Is it possible to replace the 512GB SSD in my MacBook Pro with the 1TB SSD without voiding the warranty or causing any issues with future service?

I asked Apple if they void the warranty for opening my MacBook Pro, and surprisingly they said that they don't. I did not ask them about replacing any parts, worried that they might make a note of that on their account and possibly deny me service in the future since I showed an interest in tinkering with the MacBook.

Comment: The SSD are not swappable between the two laptops.

Comment: It's been done, but I don't think it's about to become commonplace… or DIY - https://www.macrumors.com/2021/04/06/m1-mac-ram-and-ssd-upgrades-possible/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to replace the 512GB SSD in my MacBook Pro with the 1TB SSD without voiding the warranty or causing any issues with future service?

Legally speaking, yes.  You are protected under the [Magnussun-Moss Warranty Act](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-16/chapter-I/subchapter-G/part-700).  A manufacturer cannot void a warranty if you made modifications to your product without **proving** that said modification directly contributed to the failure to be covered under warranty.

[image]

Even those “Warranty Void” tamper evident stickers have no legal teeth. No company can prevent you from opening a product you own.  They will, however, put them on in the hopes you won’t challenge it in court.

Pragmatically speaking, the important question is **will Apple honor the warranty repair after you’ve made the modification?**

Likely not.  While the law is on your side, Apple can simply say “No” and (incorrectly) support their decision by pointing to their policy. You’ll need to involve a lawyer at that point and I wouldn’t be able to advise you if the “juice is worth the squeeze.”

Now, understand that I am not a lawyer, I don’t play one on YouTube or TV, and most importantly, **I’m not your legal council!!** None of this should be construed as legal advice. Seek proper legal advice as necessary.

Comment: The question is irrelevant as the swap described by the OP is impossible.

Comment: @MarcWilson - The SSD module *can* be replaced by a tech with SMD rework experience.  The T2 chip will prevent data recovery, so you'll get a Mac with a blank drive, but then you'll want to reinstall the OS anyway.

Comment: Chips, plural.  It's not a discrete module, the NAND is integrated into the logic board like any other component.  The OP thinks it's a pluggable module.

Comment: @MarcWilson, chip(s) that’s semantics.  I”m answering the questions as asked.  I’m not assuming (and don’t) the level of technical knowledge or thoughts of the OP.

Comment: @MarcWilson While it seems like you are correct that the swap of the memory modules themselves is not possible, I think the answer is still relevant as I can switch out the entire motherboard. Alternatively, I could replace the broken display on the second MacBook Pro with the display on my current MacBook Pro

Comment: I wouldn't be sure you can replace the motherboard or display.  A friend damaged her keyboard, and I took one out of another with the SAME model number ('A' and four digits) printed on the bottom.  Another time, a battery was bad, and I got one out of a working laptop with the SAME model number.  In both cases, the connectors did not have the same number of pins!!